# RSS страница, тема создана 1.1.1970

Tags: php, rss

Почему-то дата создания отображается аж 1970 года. :) Хотя в базе данных указано 
20-08-2011.

Вот код

```
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"windows-1251\"?>
<rss version=\"2.0\">
<channel>
<title>новости на сайте о рисовании</title>
<link>http://draw-art.ru</link>
<description>Здесь вы можете прочитать всякие новости посвященые искуству рисованию и всем связаным с этим</description>
<language>ru</language>";

echo "<item>".
        "<title>".strip_tags($myrow['title'])."</title>".
        "<link>http://draw-art.ru/blog_look.php?id=".$myrow['id']."</link>".
        "<description><![CDATA[".$myrow['description']."]]></description>".
        "<pubDate>".date("r",$myrow['date'])."</pubDate>".
        "<guid>http://draw-art.ru/blog_look.php?id=".$myrow['id']."</guid>".
        "</item>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, `$myrow['date']` не юниксовое время и потому обращается в 0.

Попробуйте либо модифицировать запрос

```
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as udate
```

и соотв-но выводить **`date("r",$myrow['udate'])`**

Либо переводить уже в коде:

```
date('r', strtotime($myrow['date']))
```